# Copy from clipboard to form in VB

Tags: c#, html, vb.net

So I want to write this program that transfers data from a text box to an online form using a web browser in `form1.vb`. here is my code:

```
TextBox1.SelectAll()
TextBox1.Cut()
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("input-xxxxxxx").SetAttribute("value", "")
```

My program is great until i want to put what is in `textbox1` to my form on the website. I would like to be able to paste into the second set of quotes but it would be amazing if you could put what was in `textbox1` into the `html textbox` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems trivial. Have you tried:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("input-xxxxxxx").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
```